# Special class value in PHP

Tags: php

Some code:

```
class MyClass
{
   public function __get($key)
   {
       return $this[$key];
   }

   public function __set($key, $value)
   {
       $this[$key] = $value;
   }
}

$m = new MyClass();

$m->name = 'This is my class.';
```

OR

```
$m['name'] = 'This is my class.';
```

But not working. Somebody can help me?

Comment: Use $this->$key and $m->name instead of [].

Comment: You can't make Object as Array `$m['name']`. Instead create a class scope property and use it as array.

Comment: @RahilWazir [yes you can](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php)

Comment: @kojiro This surely possible Nice to know. PHP will generate error in the case of OP code.

Answer (score 1):

In order to be able to access values in your class using array access, you have to implement the [ArrayAccess interface](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php). In order to *also* arbitrary property names dynamically, copy the sample code from that page. Once you've implemented the `ArrayAccess` methods your `__get` and `__set` will work as-is.

```
<?php

class obj implements arrayaccess {
    private $container = array();
    public function __construct() {
        $this->container = array(
            "one"   => 1,
            "two"   => 2,
            "three" => 3,
        );
    }
    public function offsetSet($offset, $value) {
        if (is_null($offset)) {
            $this->container[] = $value;
        } else {
            $this->container[$offset] = $value;
        }
    }
    public function offsetExists($offset) {
        return isset($this->container[$offset]);
    }
    public function offsetUnset($offset) {
        unset($this->container[$offset]);
    }
    public function offsetGet($offset) {
        return isset($this->container[$offset]) ? $this->container[$offset] : null;
    }
    public function __get($key) {
        return $this[$key];
    }
    public function __set($key, $value) {
        $this[$key] = $value;
    }
}

$foo = new obj();
$foo->pill = 123;
var_dump($foo->pill);
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a new property, you should do this:

```
class MyClass
{
    private $data = array();

    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        echo "Setting '$name' to '$value'\n";
        $this->data[$name] = $value;
    }

    public function __get($name)
    {
        echo "Getting '$name'\n";
        if (array_key_exists($name, $this->data)) {
            return $this->data[$name];
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can overload properties as you want in your example.

This link can give you more references:
http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members

Comment: You probably _should_ have a property that you set as good form, but it is not required. Properties assigned will just be public.

Comment: You're right, for good programming practices properties should always be declared. But he should implements the magic functions to get his example working, isn't it?

Comment: Good programming aside, the problem OP is having with the magic methods is simply that they are trying to access the properties using array access, not object.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is that inside the `__get` and `__set` methods, you are accessing the properties as an array. You need to use `$this->$key` instead of `$this[$key]`.

```
class MyClass
{
   public function __get($key)
   {
       return $this->$key;
   }

   public function __set($key, $value)
   {
       $this->$key = $value;
   }
}

$m = new MyClass();

echo "before set: \n";
var_dump($m);

$m->foo = "bar";

echo "after set: \n";
var_dump($m);
```

Example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/oNLbzq

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach

```
class MyClass
{
    private $m_var_data = array();

    public function __set($p_name, $p_value)
    {
        $this->m_var_data[$p_name] = $p_value;
    }

    public function __get($p_name)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($p_name, $this->m_var_data))
        {
            return $this->m_var_data[$p_name];
        }
    }
}


$m = new MyClass();

$m->name = 'This is my class.';
```